# Configuring cors in spring boot application. Bean CorsConfigurationSource doesnt work

Tags: java, spring, websecurity

So i cant configure cors. My angular app cant send api request because of error. 
I can do requests by soapUI and they are working fine. But from browser there is:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/backend/api/public' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I was looking for answers and they look like my class.

Im using spring boot web security.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value(value = "${auth0.apiAudience}")
    private String apiAudience;
    @Value(value = "${auth0.issuer}")
    private String issuer;


    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**",configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JwtWebSecurityConfigurer
                .forRS256(apiAudience, issuer)
                .configure(http)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/public").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/private").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/private-scoped").hasAnyAuthority("read:posts");
    }
}
```

This bean should add this cors header but it doesnt. Maybe you know any better idea of doing this?
What is difference beetwen WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/cors.html) you should add `.cors().and()` in your `configure()` method as well.

There are also other possible solutions, for example by setting the CORS-configuration specific to each endpoint as seen [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).

If you want to enable CORS for your whole application though, the first way is much prettier.

The difference between WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is, that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is used to configure anything related to the security of your webapp, like authentication and authorization. With the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter you can customize the Java-based configuration for Spring MVC.

Comment: I tried first way, and when im doing http.cors() my ide telling me that it cant find a symbol.

Comment: i can give you link to my repo

Comment: Sure, but only if you feel comfortable with that. Are you sure you imported the right HttpSecurity? For me `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity` in Spring Boot 2.0.0 has the method `cors()`.

Comment: Yes, import is coreet

Comment: i guess the only way I'd be able to help you further would be by looking at more of your code^^ What IDE are you using?

Comment: Im using NetBeans

Comment: Your `spring-security-config` dependency is old and doesn't support the cors setting. For the version you are currently using (`3.2.4`) I was also unable to use the `cors()` method. Either deleting the tag or upgrading to at least version [4.2.11](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html) should solve the problem. I'd recommend just deleting it, as it will just use the parent's version then.

Comment: this one detail about version

Comment: But still jwt configuration not working for authorized requests, have you an idea why?

Comment: I don't have any experience with "JwtWebSecurityConfigurer", I usually just configure the HttpSecurity-Object directly. If thats possible for you, I'd personally recommend that as well, since its very simple (and very similar to JwtWebSecurityConfigurer) to use. I'll check out JwtWebSecurityConfigurer later though, if you haven't found a way until then.

Comment: Im logging in my angular app. Then i get an access token. Later im making api requests to my backend and I need some kind of method that will verify this token and based on this it will give scopes that user have in this token and return resources based on them. Most of internet informations seems to be targeted for regular web apps where all login logic is in java. But i have SPA using backend for api.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I could not make the CorsConfigurationSource bean work. So I tried a different approach. I didnt use the CorsConfigurationSource bean configuration. Instead, I used the cors registry alternative or Global CORS Configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

Remove the CorsConfigurationSource configuration bean from your AuthConfig class. 
I got this snipped code from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors